# Model validity for Ordinal logistic model

Tags: regression, logistic, ordinal-data, validation

I am doing a study using OLR. The model tries to assess the satisfaction of ground level stakeholders (scale of 1(extremely dissatisfied) to 5(highly satisfied) in an urban area. The independent variables of the model are treated as continuous scale variables (variables are valued on a scale from 1 to 3). The model was developed using spss. It fulfills the proportionality odds assumption too. Apart from the goodness of fit of the model, the pseudo r square value and fulfilling the test of parallel lines assumption, is there any other method to validate the model?

When having an ordinal scale dependent variable, can we use accuracy scoring rules to predict whether the output will fall in a satisfied category or dissatisfied category of population?